# Use a txtfile to input values into pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, conways-game-of-life

Im trying to get input data into a pointer array from a txt file. Then display(print) the array as a square 2-d array of ints. Below is the tstfile. The first number 9 is to be N (which is the nxn) that sets the size of the 2d array. I was able to get this using fgetc and setting it to my int value N. Next I want to get the 9x9array in the text file and put the values into the pointer array and this is where I am having trouble. Any suggestions as to approaches I can take to do this.

```
9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int **A;
   FILE *file;
   char ch;
   int i;
   int j;
   int N;
   int t;

   if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 1 for correct execution */
   {
      printf( "you need to input one argument\n");
   }
   else {
      file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); //opens file name
      if(file == 0)
         printf("File couldnt me opened\n");
      else {
         if((ch=fgetc(file))!=1){
            N = ch - '0' ;
         }

         A = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

         for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            A[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

         while((ch=fgetc(file)) != EOF){
            i=4;
            //for (i=1;i<N;i++)
            //      for (j=1;j<N;j++)
            if(i<N)
               A[i][i]= ch2 - '0' ;

         }
         for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
               printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
         }
         fclose( file );
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to fix:

1. Reading `N`

   ```
    if((ch=fgetc(file))!=1){
       N = ch - '0' ;
    }
   ```

   This will give you the wrong `N` if the first character of the file is anything but one of the digits. Also, if is `N` greater than `9`, you will end of using the wrong value. Change it to

   ```
    if ( fscanf(file, "%d", &N) != 1 ){
       // Problem.
       // Do something about it.
    }
   ```
2. The lines you are using to read the data for the matrix don't make sense at all.

   ```
    while((ch=fgetc(file)) != EOF){
       i=4;          // Why is i set to 4 here?
       if(i<N)       // This will always be true when N >= 4
          A[i][i]= ch2 - '0' ;
   ```

   Also, you cannot use `fgetc` to read the numbers since `fgetc` doesn't skip whitespaces. Your code can be much simpler.

   ```
   for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
   {
      if ( fscanf(file, "%d", &A[i][j]) != 1 )
      {
         // Problem. 
         // Do something about it.
      }
   }
   ```